# AngularJS Dynamic Editable Table Directive

Tags: json, angularjs, directive

My goal here is to create a fully dynamic editable table directive, that only takes in a json object and outputs the editable html table.  Here is a plunker of what I have so far:

http://plnkr.co/edit/enay3g?p=preview

```
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // save
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $scope.save = function (ind) {

          $scope.headers.forEach(function(entry) {
              $scope.data[ind][entry] = 0; //I know this shouldn't be 0, but i just dont know how to get at the value of the input text box
          });



          $scope.showing = false;
        };
```

Everything works, except for the save.  I just dont know how to update the JSON object in the controller of my directive.  And I can't put an ng-model on my text boxes because then it overrides the value that is being set from the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be possible to add the `ng-model` directive on the *"edition mode text boxes"*, but the *"edition mode text boxes"* should bind a copy of the row object instead of the original one and later, on save operation replace the original one by the edited copy

```
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // showEdit
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $scope.showEdit = function (ind) {

          // ...

          $scope.edit = angular.copy($scope.data[ind]);

          // ...

        };


        ////////////////////////////////////
        // save
        ////////////////////////////////////
        $scope.save = function (ind) {

          $scope.data[ind] = $scope.edit;

          // ...
        };
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DlLnvE?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that's just what I needed.  Thanks so much Leon.